# Searching items only from a single list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-scope

Can you please guide me on how to search items from a single list? I want to use the site collection settings like Result sources option to get the details.

Should I create a page and use Search Results and Search box web part?

Can you please provide me step-by-step process on how to do that?

Comment: Folks, any suggestion???

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Result Source that contains the criteria (which list to search in).
2. Create a Search Result Page with a Search Result Web Part.
3. Configure the Query of the Search Result Web part to point to the list.
4. Configure the Search Web Part so that it "points to" your Custom Search Result Page (the one that only displays search result from the list You want.

Comment: Thank you for the information. If possible can you please provide screens of the criteria?